# TortoiseGit - Change putty key for all remotes

Tags: private-key, tortoisegit

Just having a bit of a reshuffle whilst moving off my laptop onto a new Windows PC at work now that I have stopped being freelance and gone full time.

I can't seem to find anything, but is there a setting or something which will enable me to tell ToroiseGit to use my new private key for ALL my existing remotes?

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseGit -> Settings -> Git -> Remote

For each remote, enter putty key

Comment: I tried that. Right clicked on desktop to get into git settings , but there doesn't seem to be anything about remotes in there.

Comment: To be honest, I think I've done most of the sites now one by one as I've been needing to work on them.

Comment: You need to open Settings in a specific repository, and add a remote.

Comment: That's what I was originally trying to avoid, but have had to do for each site anyway :-(